# How to POST JSon with a Bearer Token

Tags: c#, json, api, post, bearer-token

I am able to do a GET with similar code and the Bearer Token, but cannot seem to do the POST.

When I copy/paste the Json, the URL and the Bearer Token into Postman it works perfectly. But when doing it from the C# I get this error:

> "StatusCode: 400, ReasonPhrase: 'Bad Request', Version: 1.1, Content:
>   System.Net.Http.StreamContent, Headers: { Transfer-Encoding: chunked
>   Connection: keep-alive Expect-CT: max-age=604800,
>   report-uri="https://report-uri.cloudflare.com/cdn-cgi/beacon/expect-ct"
>   CF-RAY: 4c190ad8ad786539-SYD Date: Wed, 03 Apr 2019 06:38:54 GMT
>   Set-Cookie: __cfduid=dc0232e99fa0fefc0bd728258229dd5d51554273534;
>   expires=Thu, 02-Apr-20 06:38:54 GMT; path=/; domain=.paymentsapi.io;
>   HttpOnly; Secure Server: cloudflare X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
>   Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8 }"

Can anyone see what I'm doing wrong?

Thanks in advance.

```
JsonSerializerSettings jss = new JsonSerializerSettings();
string strValue = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(TestMaster, jss);
lblJSon.Text = strValue;        // This Json is valid
ByteArrayContent bytecontent = new ByteArrayContent(System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(strValue));
bytecontent.Headers.ContentType = new MediaTypeHeaderValue("application/json");

string AccessToken = lblToken.Text;

HttpClient tRequest = new HttpClient();
tRequest.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", AccessToken);

Task<HttpResponseMessage> getTask = tRequest.PostAsJsonAsync(new Uri(strURL).ToString(), bytecontent);

HttpResponseMessage urlContents = await getTask;

Console.WriteLine("urlContents.ToString");
lblEDDR.Text = urlContents.ToString();
```

Comment: Probably because of "System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes", try using System.Convert.FromBase64String

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`PostAsJsonAsync` converts your `ByteArrayContent` into a json object. You can use ether `PostAsJsonAsync` directly with your `TestMaster` like so:

```cs
string AccessToken = lblToken.Text;

HttpClient tRequest = new HttpClient();
tRequest.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", AccessToken);

Task<HttpResponseMessage> getTask = tRequest.PostAsJsonAsync(new Uri(strURL).ToString(), TestMaster);

HttpResponseMessage urlContents = await getTask;

Console.WriteLine("urlContents.ToString");
lblEDDR.Text = urlContents.ToString();
```

Or you convert `TestMaster` to Json and use `PostAsync` with a `StringContent` object. Like so:

```cs
JsonSerializerSettings jss = new JsonSerializerSettings();
string strValue = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(TestMaster, jss);
lblJSon.Text = strValue;        // This Json is valid
StringContent strcontent = new StringContent (strValue);
bytecontent.Headers.ContentType = new MediaTypeHeaderValue("application/json");

string AccessToken = lblToken.Text;

HttpClient tRequest = new HttpClient();
tRequest.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", AccessToken);

Task<HttpResponseMessage> getTask = tRequest.PostAsync(new Uri(strURL).ToString(), bytecontent);

HttpResponseMessage urlContents = await getTask;

Console.WriteLine("urlContents.ToString");
lblEDDR.Text = urlContents.ToString();
```

Comment: Thanks @Rain336 ... Now getting this error  :-    

StatusCode: 201, ReasonPhrase: 'Created', Version: 1.1, Content: System.Net.Http.StreamContent, Headers: { Transfer-Encoding: chunked Connection: keep-alive Expect-CT: max-age=604800, report-uri="https://rep..lare.com/cdn-cgi/beacon/expect-ct" CF-RAY: 4c193cf0689219aa-SYD Date: Wed, 03 Apr 2019 07:13:06 GMT Location: https://sandbox.re..ecure Server: cloudflare X-Powered-By: ASP.NET Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8 }
(truncated)

Comment: That's not an error message. The Server responded with StatusCode `201 Created` which means the request was successful.

Comment: oh ... lol ... can you tell I'm new at this? Hopefully last question then ... how do I get the response body? in Postman I get a JSon string back. I've looked at urlContents under debug mode, but can't see it.

Comment: [`urlContents.Content.ReadAsStringAsync()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.http.httpcontent.readasstringasync?view=netframework-4.7.2) reads the `HttpResponseMessage` as a string. There are also other methods for handling a binary response. Also it's an Async Method so you need to use `await` on it.